# adding noise to a signal in python

Tags: python

I want to add some random noise to some 100 bin signal that I am simulating in Python - to make it more realistic.

On a basic level, my first thought was to go bin by bin and just generate a random number between a certain range and add or subtract this from the signal.

I was hoping (as this is python) that there might a more intelligent way to do this via numpy or something. (I suppose that ideally a number drawn from a gaussian distribution and added to each bin would be better also.)

Thank you in advance of any replies.

---

I'm just at the stage of planning my code, so I don't have anything to show. I was just thinking that there might be a more sophisticated way of generating the noise.

In terms out output, if I had 10 bins with the following values:

Bin 1: 1
Bin 2: 4
Bin 3: 9
Bin 4: 16
Bin 5: 25
Bin 6: 25
Bin 7: 16
Bin 8: 9
Bin 9: 4
Bin 10: 1

I just wondered if there was a pre-defined function that could add noise to give me something like:

Bin 1: 1.13
Bin 2: 4.21
Bin 3: 8.79
Bin 4: 16.08
Bin 5: 24.97
Bin 6: 25.14
Bin 7: 16.22
Bin 8: 8.90
Bin 9: 4.02
Bin 10: 0.91

If not, I will just go bin-by-bin and add a number selected from a gaussian distribution to each one.

Thank you.

---

It's actually a signal from a radio telescope that I am simulating. I want to be able to eventually choose the signal to noise ratio of my simulation.

Comment: Please demonstrate code you've tried, or a specific problem you're encountering.  Sample inputs and desired output would go a long way as well.

Comment: What kind of signal is it? What kind of noise do you want to introduce? "Realistic" depends on the type of signal. Audio noise is not the same as image noise, for example.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

You can generate a noise array, and add it to your signal

```
import numpy as np

noise = np.random.normal(0,1,100)

# 0 is the mean of the normal distribution you are choosing from
# 1 is the standard deviation of the normal distribution
# 100 is the number of elements you get in array noise
```

Comment: In some contexts, it might make more sense to multiply your signal by a noise array (centered around 1), rather than adding a noise array, but of course that depends on the nature of the noise that you're trying to simulate.

Comment: how can we generate non-gaussian random noise?

Comment: @EdwardLoper could you give an example of a noise/signal where it makes sense to multiply instead of add the noise array?

Answer (score 108):

For those trying to make the connection between [SNR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio) and a normal random variable generated by numpy:

[1] [image: SNR ratio], where it's important to keep in mind that P is *average* power.

Or in dB:
[2] [image: SNR dB2]

In this case, we already have a signal and we want to generate noise to give us a desired SNR.

While noise can come in different [flavors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_(signal_processing)) depending on what you are modeling, a good start (especially for this radio telescope example) is [Additive White Gaussian Noise (AWGN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_white_Gaussian_noise). As stated in the previous answers, to model AWGN you need to add a zero-mean gaussian random variable to your original signal. The variance of that random variable will affect the *average* noise power.

For a Gaussian random variable X, the average power [image: Ep], also known as the second [moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments), is
[3]  [image: Ex]

So for white noise, [image: Ex] and the average power is then equal to the variance [image: Ex].

When modeling this in python, you can either
1. Calculate variance based on a desired SNR and a set of existing measurements, which would work if you expect your measurements to have fairly consistent amplitude values.
2. Alternatively, you could set noise power to a known level to match something like receiver noise. Receiver noise could be measured by pointing the telescope into free space and calculating average power.

Either way, it's important to make sure that you add noise to your signal and take averages in the linear space and not in dB units.

Here's some code to generate a signal and plot voltage, power in Watts, and power in dB:

```
# Signal Generation
# matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(1, 100, 1000)
x_volts = 10*np.sin(t/(2*np.pi))
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(t, x_volts)
plt.title('Signal')
plt.ylabel('Voltage (V)')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.show()

x_watts = x_volts ** 2
plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.plot(t, x_watts)
plt.title('Signal Power')
plt.ylabel('Power (W)')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.show()

x_db = 10 * np.log10(x_watts)
plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.plot(t, x_db)
plt.title('Signal Power in dB')
plt.ylabel('Power (dB)')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.show()
```

[image: Generated Signal]

Here's an example for adding AWGN based on a desired SNR:

```
# Adding noise using target SNR

# Set a target SNR
target_snr_db = 20
# Calculate signal power and convert to dB 
sig_avg_watts = np.mean(x_watts)
sig_avg_db = 10 * np.log10(sig_avg_watts)
# Calculate noise according to [2] then convert to watts
noise_avg_db = sig_avg_db - target_snr_db
noise_avg_watts = 10 ** (noise_avg_db / 10)
# Generate an sample of white noise
mean_noise = 0
noise_volts = np.random.normal(mean_noise, np.sqrt(noise_avg_watts), len(x_watts))
# Noise up the original signal
y_volts = x_volts + noise_volts

# Plot signal with noise
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(t, y_volts)
plt.title('Signal with noise')
plt.ylabel('Voltage (V)')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.show()
# Plot in dB
y_watts = y_volts ** 2
y_db = 10 * np.log10(y_watts)
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(t, 10* np.log10(y_volts**2))
plt.title('Signal with noise (dB)')
plt.ylabel('Power (dB)')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.show()
```

[image: Signal with target SNR]

And here's an example for adding AWGN based on a known noise power:

```
# Adding noise using a target noise power

# Set a target channel noise power to something very noisy
target_noise_db = 10

# Convert to linear Watt units
target_noise_watts = 10 ** (target_noise_db / 10)

# Generate noise samples
mean_noise = 0
noise_volts = np.random.normal(mean_noise, np.sqrt(target_noise_watts), len(x_watts))

# Noise up the original signal (again) and plot
y_volts = x_volts + noise_volts

# Plot signal with noise
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(t, y_volts)
plt.title('Signal with noise')
plt.ylabel('Voltage (V)')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.show()
# Plot in dB
y_watts = y_volts ** 2
y_db = 10 * np.log10(y_watts)
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(t, 10* np.log10(y_volts**2))
plt.title('Signal with noise')
plt.ylabel('Power (dB)')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.show()
```

[image: Signal with target noise level]

Answer (score 83):

... And for those who - like me - are very early in their numpy learning curve,

```
import numpy as np
pure = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
signal = pure + noise
```

Answer (score 13):

For those who want to add noise to a multi-dimensional dataset loaded within a pandas dataframe or even a numpy ndarray, here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
# create a sample dataset with dimension (2,2)
# in your case you need to replace this with 
# clean_signal = pd.read_csv("your_data.csv")   
clean_signal = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=list('AB'), dtype=float) 
print(clean_signal)
"""
print output: 
    A    B
0  1.0  2.0
1  3.0  4.0
"""
import numpy as np 
mu, sigma = 0, 0.1 
# creating a noise with the same dimension as the dataset (2,2) 
noise = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, [2,2]) 
print(noise)

"""
print output: 
array([[-0.11114313,  0.25927152],
       [ 0.06701506, -0.09364186]])
"""
signal = clean_signal + noise
print(signal)
"""
print output: 
          A         B
0  0.888857  2.259272
1  3.067015  3.906358
"""
```

Answer (score 5):

In real life you wish to simulate a signal with white noise. You should add to your signal random points that have Normal Gaussian distribution. If we speak about a device that have sensitivity given in unit/SQRT(Hz) then you need to devise standard deviation of your points from it. Here I give function "white_noise" that does this for you, an the rest of a code is demonstration and check if it does what it should.

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal

"""
parameters: 
rhp - spectral noise density unit/SQRT(Hz)
sr  - sample rate
n   - no of points
mu  - mean value, optional

returns:
n points of noise signal with spectral noise density of rho
"""
def white_noise(rho, sr, n, mu=0):
    sigma = rho * np.sqrt(sr/2)
    noise = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, n)
    return noise

rho = 1 
sr = 1000
n = 1000
period = n/sr
time = np.linspace(0, period, n)
signal_pure = 100*np.sin(2*np.pi*13*time)
noise = white_noise(rho, sr, n)
signal_with_noise = signal_pure + noise

f, psd = signal.periodogram(signal_with_noise, sr)

print("Mean spectral noise density = ",np.sqrt(np.mean(psd[50:])), "arb.u/SQRT(Hz)")

plt.plot(time, signal_with_noise)
plt.plot(time, signal_pure)
plt.xlabel("time (s)")
plt.ylabel("signal (arb.u.)")
plt.show()

plt.semilogy(f[1:], np.sqrt(psd[1:]))
plt.xlabel("frequency (Hz)")
plt.ylabel("psd (arb.u./SQRT(Hz))")
#plt.axvline(13, ls="dashed", color="g")
plt.axhline(rho, ls="dashed", color="r")
plt.show()
```

[image: Signal with noise]

[image: PSD]

Answer (score 4):

## AWGN Similar to Matlab Function

```py
def awgn(sinal):
    regsnr=54
    sigpower=sum([math.pow(abs(sinal[i]),2) for i in range(len(sinal))])
    sigpower=sigpower/len(sinal)
    noisepower=sigpower/(math.pow(10,regsnr/10))
    noise=math.sqrt(noisepower)*(np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=len(sinal)))
    return noise
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-5.0, 5.0, 0.1)

y = np.power(x,2)

noise = 2 * np.random.normal(size=x.size)

ydata = y + noise

plt.plot(x, ydata,  'bo')
plt.plot(x,y, 'r') 
plt.ylabel('y data')
plt.xlabel('x data')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Awesome answers from Akavall and Noel (that's what worked for me). Also, I saw some comments about different distributions. A solution that I also tried was to make test over my variable and find what distribution it was closer.

```
numpy.random
```

has different distributions that can be used, it can be seen in its documentation:

[documentation numpy.random](https://numpy.org/doc/1.16/reference/routines.random.html#module-numpy.random)

As an example from a different distribution (example referenced from Noel's answer):

```
import numpy as np
pure = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
noise = np.random.lognormal(0, 1, 100)
signal = pure + noise
print(pure[:10])
print(signal[:10])
```

I hope this can help someone looking for this specific branch from the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome answers above. I recently had a need to generate simulated data and this is what I landed up using. Sharing in-case helpful to others as well,

```
import logging
__name__ = "DataSimulator"
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def generate_simulated_data(add_anomalies:bool=True, random_state:int=42):
    rnd_state = np.random.RandomState(random_state)
    time = np.linspace(0, 200, num=2000)
    pure = 20*np.sin(time/(2*np.pi))

    # concatenate on the second axis; this will allow us to mix different data 
    # distribution
    data = np.c_[pure]
    mu = np.mean(data)
    sd = np.std(data)
    logger.info(f"Data shape : {data.shape}. mu: {mu} with sd: {sd}")
    data_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Value'])
    data_df['Index'] = data_df.index.values

    # Adding gaussian jitter
    jitter = 0.3*rnd_state.normal(mu, sd, size=data_df.shape[0])
    data_df['with_jitter'] = data_df['Value'] + jitter

    index_further_away = None
    if add_anomalies:
        # As per the 68-95-99.7 rule(also known as the empirical rule) mu+-2*sd 
        # covers 95.4% of the dataset.
        # Since, anomalies are considered to be rare and typically within the 
        # 5-10% of the data; this filtering
        # technique might work 
        #for us(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule)
        indexes_furhter_away = np.where(np.abs(data_df['with_jitter']) > (mu + 
         2*sd))[0]
        logger.info(f"Number of points further away : 
        {len(indexes_furhter_away)}. Indexes: {indexes_furhter_away}")
        # Generate a point uniformly and embed it into the dataset
        random = rnd_state.uniform(0, 5, 1)
        data_df.loc[indexes_furhter_away, 'with_jitter'] +=  
        random*data_df.loc[indexes_furhter_away, 'with_jitter']
    return data_df, indexes_furhter_away
```