# Data sets generation for binary logistic regression

Tags: python, numpy

I have classifier line in the form of `y = mx + c`.

I would to generate random data points that are above and below this line.

I tried using the `numpy` `random` function but I am not able figure how to specifically generate random data sets.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far, and why it is not working. We are not a code writing service. As a new user taking the [tour] and reading [mcve] are great places to start.

Comment: `noise=numpy.random.random(100)`, `x=numpy.linspace(0,1,100)`, `y=m*x+c+scale*noise`? You can also use differently distributed random numbers -- see [numpy.random](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html).

Comment: Thank you!. I am completely  new to coding i didnt knew i could have multiplied noise with a scale factor. If suppose i have region like eclipse and i want to generate points just the like the previous one. How should i go about that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean -- can you maybe update your question?

Comment: Suppose classifier is an ellipse instead of a straight line, and i would like to generate random points inside and outside of that ellipse,the way i did for a line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding noise to a signal in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058340/adding-noise-to-a-signal-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You could try scikit-learn's [`make_classification`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_classification.html) utility function:

> Generate a random n-class classification problem.

For example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_features=2, random_state=444)
```