# Denoise a Signal using wavelets in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to denoise a signal using wavelets.
I have generated an ideal sine wave of two different frequencies and added noise to it.
Please let me know how to denoise the signal "I_as_fft_array_noise" as mentioned in the below code using wavelets.

Import Libraries

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pywt
import sys
```

Define the signal sine signal of 100Hz and 50Hz

```
Fs_fft = 1e4          # Sampling Frequency
Pi=np.pi
N1 = (1e5)/2

time1 = np.arange(N1) / float(Fs_fft)  
f1 = 100
x1 = 1000*np.sin(2*Pi*f1*time1)

time2 = np.arange(N1,2*N1) / float(Fs_fft)
f2 = 50
x2 = 500*np.sin(2*Pi*f2*time2)

T_fft_array    =np.concatenate((time1,time2))
I_as_fft_array = np.concatenate((x1,x2))
```

Adding noise using target SNR

Reference: [adding noise to a signal in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058340/adding-noise-to-a-signal-in-python)

```
I_as_fft_array_watts = I_as_fft_array ** 2
I_as_fft_array_db = 10 * np.log10(I_as_fft_array_watts)


target_snr_db = 20                                      

sig_avg_watts = np.mean(I_as_fft_array_watts)            

sig_avg_db = 10 * np.log10(sig_avg_watts)
noise_avg_db = sig_avg_db - target_snr_db   
noise_avg_watts = 10 ** (noise_avg_db / 10)
mean_noise = 0                                  
noise_volts = np.random.normal(mean_noise, np.sqrt(noise_avg_watts), len(I_as_fft_array_watts))
I_as_fft_array_noise = I_as_fft_array + noise_volts
```

Plot ideal signal

```
plt.plot(T_fft_array , I_as_fft_array)
plt.title('Ideal Signal')
plt.ylabel('Current [A]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()
```

Plot signal with noise

```
plt.plot(T_fft_array, I_as_fft_array_noise)
plt.title('Signal with noise')
plt.ylabel('Voltage (V)')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.show()
```