# How to add noise to a wav file in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, audio, wav

I just started working with matplotlib and numpy. I need to add noise to an audio signal, in Python.

In order to do that, I need to receive the original audio signal and the noise amplitude, and then returning the original audio signal with the noise in it.

I have to use the rand function from numpy.random. The amplitude is what is supposed to help me get those values.

So far this is what I have:

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as spiowf
import sounddevice as sd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def noise(data, samplerate):
    (ns, nc) = data.shape 
    Ts = 1 / samplerate 
    dur = ns / samplerate # audio duration

    random = np.random.rand(0, 100)
    sd.play(data, samplerate, blocking=True)

def main():
    fName = "saxriff.wav"
    [samplerate, data] = spiowf.read(fName)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How can I do the rest?

Comment: Could you please phrase this, or a part of it, as a specific question, like, "I need to X"  (where X is a specific programming problem, like "calculate the amplitude of the `data` waveform", not "finish my homework").

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adding noise to a signal in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058340/adding-noise-to-a-signal-in-python)

Comment: 1 - I need to create the noise using numpy.random.rand, but I don't know what values to give (do I get them through the noise amplitude?);

2 - I need to add the noise to the audio signal. I usually read the audio signal with sd.play(data, samplerate, blocking=True), but in this case I think I would need to replace the samplerate, but I'm not sure...

Comment: @Squalexy: 1) there is no *a priori* value for noised based on the amplitude; it just depends what : you want to do, what your goal is, what the assignment it, etc. Sometimes one wants noise that dependent on the signal; sometimes one wants white noise (gaussian) but often something else; sometimes that noise is stationary and sometime varying; it really all depends on the problem. 2) To add the noise, typically the easiest thing and what people usually do is to calculate the noise to match the sample rate, and if the noise and the sample are both numpy arrays it's just `r = n + s`.

Comment: @Squalexy: it's not that people don't want to answer in general. If this were presented as a well defined problem you'd have a clear answer with code by now. I'm just trying to let you know why that hasn't happened.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, I'm sorry for being so vague but I'm just a beginner being given a sort of advanced assignment so I can't be more specific than this. But with that said, you talking about numpy arrays helped me understand this better and I finally completed this assignment. Since the data is a matrix and random.rand generates a matrix, I matched the ranges and added both values like you just showed :) thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Squalexy: I'm glad that you got it to work and that my advice was helpful. For SO, it would have been best to have an answer that you could accept, with the idea that it would help other people in the future. By far, the best way to make that happen is if the question is posted with an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and for data processing, with either data that other people can download, or that you create in the example. And your answers will be better and quicker; so maybe try an mcve for your next question, and a clear question, of course.