# How to create add gaussian noise on an image

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

I want to create a function to add gaussian noise to a single input that I will later use.
I'm using the imageio module in Python.

```py
def gaussian_noise(x, var):
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adding noise to a signal in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058340/adding-noise-to-a-signal-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

I thought x is the tensor you want to add gaussian noise to, and var is the variance of gaussian noise.

Your question is vague, but you can add gaussian noise like this:

```py
import torch

def gaussian_noise(x, var):
  return torch.normal(0, var, size=x.shape)

T = torch.ones(4, 5)
T += gaussian_noise(T, 0.1)
print(T)
```